# Factorial starts with a even number

Tags: java, algorithm

I want to collect all the numbers in the range [a, b] whose factorial starts with an even number.

**For example:**

```
a = 1, b = 10
```

**Answer:**

```
2 3 4 8
```

**Explanation:**

```
2! = 2 = starts with even
3! = 6 = starts with even
4! = 24 = starts with even
8! = 40320 = starts with even
```

**Constraints:**

1 <= a,b <= 100

Here is my code:

```
List<Integer> process(int a, int b) {
    long base = i;
    for(int i=1; i<=a; i++) base *= i;
    
    if(even(base)) list.add(a);
    
    for(int i=a+1; i<=b; i++) {
        base *= i;
        if(even(base)) list.add(i);
    }
    return list;
}

boolean even(long k) {
    int z = ("" + k).charAt(0) - '0';
    return z % 2 == 0;
}
```

This was asked some days back in a coding challenge, when I implemented this, 6 hidden test cases were failing out of 15 test cases. I am not able to find what is the bug in this code.

Comment: Fun fact: Every factorial `n!` where `n >= 2` is an even number. An even number must be divisible by 2, and thus for `n! = n * (n-1) * ... 3 * 2 * 1 = 2x`, where `x` is the factorial product before 2.

Comment: "*I want to collect all the numbers in the range [a, b] whose factorial is an even number.*" - `∀(n ∈ N): n > 1 ↔ n % 2 = 0`.

Comment: For those who didn't realize, the question is how many have a factorial that STARTS with an even number.

Comment: @btilly good catch, overlooked those comments. I'm tempted to think there might be a closed form solution for this as well though.

Comment: Your code can't be compiled. Also, long values does not have charAt method

Comment: @Melron, I corrected that now.

Comment: Given the constraints, the values can be calculated ahead of time and put in a List, then just pull the items that are in the input range.

Comment: If 1 < a < b < 100, why not just precompute the answer and look it up when needed?

Comment: [2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 39, 40, 43, 44, 47, 49, 52, 53, 54, 57, 58, 60, 65, 68, 71, 72, 73, 75, 79, 82, 85, 86, 87]

Comment: Most factorials for `n` where  `1 <= n <= 100` will greatly exceed the capacity of a `long`.

Comment: I noticed your range is described as `[a,b]` which in math represents a closed interval.  In java, ranges are typically half open `[a,b)` with `b` being excluded.  Just wondering which it was.

Comment: I tried `sqrt(π) e^(-n) n^(n + 1/2) 2^(ceiling(-(2 log(n) n - 2 n + log(2 n π))/log(100)) + 1/2) 5^ceiling(-(2 log(n) n - 2 n + log(2 n π))/log(100))`, which I believe is the last number, but it outputs `inf` all the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am using `BigInteger` to solve this. To help speed up the process I am memoizing subsequent factorial computations as starting points for future ones.  I also set up a record to hold pertinent data to facilitate the process.

There may be a mathematical way to predict the parity of the first digit but for now, this seems to work.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class FactorialStartsWithEven {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       
        List<Integer> list = getForRange(1, 20);
        System.out.println(list);
    }
```

prints

```
[2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

```
public static List<Integer> getForRange(int start, int end) {
    List<Integer> results = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
       if(factorialStartsWithEven(i)) {
           results.add(i);
       }
    }
    return results;
}
```

Record declared to hold the data

```
    record Fact(BigInteger fact, int n, boolean parity) {}
```

Initialize the Memo for computed factorials

```
    static List<Fact> computed = new ArrayList<>(List.of(
            new Fact(BigInteger.ONE, 0, false),
            new Fact(BigInteger.ONE, 1, false),
            new Fact(BigInteger.TWO, 2, true)));
```

- If the value already exists, just look it up and return the boolean.
- else, get the last computed value and start computing up to `n`, adding each factorial to the list as it is computed.

```
    public static boolean factorialStartsWithEven(int n) {
        if (n < computed.size()) {
            return computed.get(n).parity;
        }
        Fact f = computed.get(computed.size()-1);
        BigInteger b = f.fact;
        Fact result = null;
        for (int k = f.n+1; k <= n; k++) {
            b = b.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(k));
            result = new Fact(b, k, Character.digit(b.toString().charAt(0),10) % 2 == 0);
            computed.add(result);
        }
        return result.parity;
    }
```

Comment: Nice! Your answer is full of valuable things and the latest data structures, helpful to learners.

Answer (score 1):

This is a filthy solution - I'm not really recommending it, just posting it here for interest - but the lower-value digits will have relatively little impact on the first digit. As such:

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
public class Main {  
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    long acc = 1;
    int limit = (int)Math.log10(Long.MAX_VALUE);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++){
      int accLength = (int)Math.log10(acc) + 1;
      int iLength = (int)Math.log10(i) + 1;
      //System.out.printf("Acc :%s, accLength : %s, i : %s, iLength : %s \n", acc, accLength, i, iLength);
      if (accLength + iLength >= limit){
        //System.out.printf("Adjusting %s by %s", acc, iLength);
        acc = acc / (long)(Math.pow(10, iLength));
        //System.out.println(" becomes: " + acc);
      }
      acc = acc * i;
      System.out.printf("acc is %s\n", acc);
    }
  }
}
```

Forgive the sloppiness, I haven't worked in Java in a long time.

Anyway, this solution is based on the fact that trailing digits won't contribute to the leading digits very much. So - and don't tell anyone I said it was okay to do math this way - I'm just discarding them, dividing by some power of 10, and only keeping about as much as I can fit in a `long`.

I'm actually uncertain how long this will remain accurate for. I'm curious if anyone wants to weigh in on that, but my suspicion is that this will hold up until the digits of `i` (the thing we're taking the factorial of) become significant relative to the length of a long.

Answer (score 0):

Here's Ruby code that solves this for your parameters. I don't know Java but it will be easy to translate. There's no point solving the hard generic problem when your input parameters are so modest (b <= 100 in particular). My array stops at 87 because 88! through 100! all have odd leading digits.

```
def get_list(a, b)
  arr = [2, 3, 4, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20, 23, 24, 26, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 39, 40, 43, 44, 47, 49, 52, 53, 54, 57, 58, 60, 65, 68, 71, 72, 73, 75, 79, 82, 85, 86, 87]
  
  list = []
  
  arr.each do |val|
    list.append(val) if a <= val && val <= b
  end
  
  return list
end

> get_list(10, 20)
=> [12, 13, 14, 16, 18, 20]
```

Answer (score -2):

Is simpler than the way you thought that.

1. Loop from a to b
2. Calc the factorial of the loop index
3. Check if the 1st character of the generated index is even and add it to your list
4. Print the list

   ```
   private static List<Integer> process(int a, int b)
   {
       List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
       for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
       {
           final int factorial = calcFactorial(i);
           if (factorialStartsWithEven(factorial))
               list.add(i);
       }
       return list;
   }

   private static boolean factorialStartsWithEven(int factorial)
   {
       final String strVal = String.valueOf(factorial);
       final int intVal = Integer.valueOf(strVal.charAt(0));
       return intVal % 2 == 0;
   }

   private static int calcFactorial(int n)
   {
       if (n == 0)
           return 1;
       return (n * calcFactorial(n - 1));
   }
   ```

Comment: `13!` is larger than the maximum value that can be stored in an `int`.